# Multiplying a chi-square distribution by a constant

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

If $X\sim\chi^{2}(3)$. What is the distribution of $2X$?

Answer (score 2):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Related_distributions): If $X\sim\chi^{2}(\nu)$
and $c>0$, then $cX\sim\Gamma(k = \nu/2, \theta = 2c)$. Here, $\Gamma$ denotes the [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with $k$ and $\theta$ being the shape and scale, respectively.

In your case, we have $2X\sim\Gamma(3/2, 4)$.